# Can Dapper handle dynamic column header

Tags: dapper

I have a stored procedure that always returns a list of strings.  However, based on the parameters passed to the stored procedure, the column heading for the list of strings will change.  Is Dapper able to handle this?  If so, how should it be handled?

```
                conn.Open();
                var p = new DynamicParameters();
                p.Add("Search_Function_CD", searchFunction, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.Add("Search_Value", searchValue, DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
                p.Add("o_resultset", dbType: DbType.Object, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
                var Results = (IDictionary<string, object>)conn.Query(sql: CommonConstants.ProcedureConstants.PKG_GET_SEARCH_RESULTS, param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                foreach (object o in Results)
                {
                    string element = Results.Values.ElementAt(1) as string;
                    searchResults.Add(element);
                }
                conn.Close();
                return searchResults;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the value by a dynamic column name or index:

```
var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)con.Query("select * from Products").First();

string name = row["ProductName"]; // column name 'ProductName'
// or:
string name = row.Values.ElementAt(1) as string; // column index 1
```

Comment: I'm not not trying to get the column name, I'm need the list of strings.

Comment: Have you even tried the example? .... You should definately learn some more about Databases.... PS: this gives you the first result set

Comment: I'll like to add to get Column name you can use `row.Keys.ElementAt(indexPosition)` function.